# How to wire a custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Grails 5

Tags: spring-boot, grails, spring-security

We need to customize the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to allow CORS headers on authentication. I created the custom security config:

```
package priz.api.security

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

@CompileStatic
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.IGNORED_ORDER)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(new PermissiveCorsConfigurationSource()).and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**").permitAll();
    }

    private static class PermissiveCorsConfigurationSource implements CorsConfigurationSource {
        /**
         * Return a {@link CorsConfiguration} based on the incoming request.
         *
         * @param request
         * @return the associated {@link CorsConfiguration}, or {@code null} if none
         */
        @Override
        public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(final HttpServletRequest request) {
            final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
            return configuration;
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems that it is not getting used. Do I need to wire it somehow got Grails to use it?